# Error al usar el comando Expo start

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trato de usar ese comando pero me marca un error de que no se pudo instalar el modulo ***sharp***.

> PS C:\Users\luis.leyva\Proyectos\AppSysamher> expo start
>   Starting project at C:\Users\luis.leyva\Proyectos\AppSysamher
>   Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
>   Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
>   Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module
>   The module '\?\C:\Users\luis.leyva\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
>   the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
>
> - Ensure the version of Node.js used at install time matches that used at runtime
> - Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
> - Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues
>     PS C:\Users\luis.leyva\Proyectos\AppSysamher>

Comment: Prueba borrando la carpeta node_modules y ejecutando el comando npm install (que la vuelve a crear)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]